# question on NSSecureTextField & Window management in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am lil bit new to objective C. Here is my requirement. I have a small button in my iPad App on pressing it takes me to a config screen. The requirement is I want to make this button secure. Only users with password can proceed to the config screen. If they do not enter the rite password, it should return back the main screen.

So, I though of something like, on clicking the button open a new window and provide a text field where the users enter the password and based on that move to config screen or not.

Can some help me with a proper pseudo code for me to try ?

Here is my button,

```
-(IBAction) goBack 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need single check, compare use entered password with app password if both match then move forward to config screen.else error message.

instructions(not in obj-c)

```
if userEnterPassword==app.password
    push->configView
else
   msg(error);
```

some thing like this.

**Edit:**

You can save password in NSUserDefaults

```
-(void)setPassCode
{

    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
    {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:passCodeTextField.text forKey:@"lock"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];


    } 
}

and these line for checking in a button click

    -(IBAction)checkPassCode
    {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *passcode== [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"lock"];


    if([passcode isEqualToString:lockTextField.text])
        {   
              Second *obj=[[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
              [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
              [obj release];
        }
    else
    {
      UIAlertView *confirmAlertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:@"NO",nil];
            [confirmAlertView show];
            [confirmAlertView release];

    }
    }
```

**Edit:**

.h file

```
 UITextField *lockTextField;
```

and make it property with IBOutlet

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *lockTextField;
```

and in .m synthsize it

```
@synthesize lockTextField;
```

and make connection form IB.see the tutorial how to make connection which i suggest you.

now you can access this textField.

Comment: I know about that :) but do not know how that needs to be done in Objective c :) Hence I asked for a pseudo code Obj c itself

Comment: Ishu, there are lot of errors. It says passCodeTextField undeclared.

Comment: dear you need to declare it in .h file and make connection with your text field then you can access.

Comment: see thes tutorials http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/07/first-iphone-application.html , it shows how you can use controls.

Comment: Ishu, you mean to say I will have to modify .xib files as well. I ask this because I am new to this. :)

Comment: Ishu, thanks! I have set up the IB. but one more small issue. It says Second undeclared? what does that mean?

Comment: Here you dont need to direct copy paste.actually i am giving you idea.what is your work,just make object for your config view here and push that view.pass object of your view.

Comment: Ishu, thanks a ton:) I have got the thing working now. Next problem, it does not not pop up a text box at all for me to enter the passcode. It just shows the error dialog box

Comment: Also, I have associated the setPasscode method for the click of the button from IB

Comment: Ishu, as told can you help me further here. I have mentioned the problem in my previous append

Comment: send that problem in other thread or give me the link if you already asked that.

Comment: Next problem, it does not not pop up a text box at all for me to enter the passcode?. It just shows the error dialog box per the above.

Comment: i cound not understand your problem.

Comment: Ok, now when I click the button it just opens up a alert box as per your code above. It does not provide me a prompt for me to enter the passcode. Hope this is clear

Comment: if you want any kind of code on click of alert button then you need to set delegate:self see in UIAlertView alloc line.and call a delegate - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Comment: You need to read documentation and some tutorial which make you familiar to objective c and UI controls.